# member function specialization of an already specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm struggling with the following problem. Basically I have a template struct and a specialization.

```
template<class T>
struct A
  {
  };


// Specialization of A for int
template<>
struct A<int>
  {
    template<class B>
    void f(B b)
      {
      // Do stuff
      }
  };
```

Is it possible to specialize A::f ?

something like:

```
template<>
template<>
void A<int>::f<double>(double b)
  {
  // do stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you only need one `template<>` (`A<int>` is already fully specialized here, and the member function is only defined in the specialization `A<int>` and not in the primary template)

```
template<>
void A<int>::f<double>(double b)
{
    std::cout << "specialization" << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f114541afc21ae5)

Comment: for some reason I was sure I needed the two template<> thanks

Comment: @user3770392 No, since `A<int>` is already explicitly specialized above. You are not specializing both `A` and `f`, as `f` is only defined in the specialization `A<int>`, so you're only specializing `f` inside `A<int>`. This example is where you need to use 2 `template<>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59a0616ca5770490, as you're fully specializing a member function in a template class, so need to specialize both.